# Returning True for comparing last two elements in a list ( loop ) - Python

Tags: python

I have a question of a sort but I am stuck on this part:

```
int_listed = int_to_list(3524)


def is_ascending(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] <= lst[i+1]:
            return False



print(is_ascending(int_listed))
```

---

My problem is the is_ascending function.
If my numbers are 3524, 3456, any number of which there is one number that right>left, so I get False and its good.
But I want to get True if all numbers from left>right.
I can do so it will go True, but that means that if I get 5432 - I wont get True, I will get list out of range index error.

```
def is_ascending(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] <= lst[i+1]:
            return False
        elif lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            pass
```

Or I can make it get true if it gets 5434 ( Which is not good ).

```
def is_ascending(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] <= lst[i+1]:
            return False
        if lst[-i] > lst[-i+1]:
            return True
```

I dont know how to get the True only on the last part of the number, I mean.
If I get 5432, so the return True will count only one 32,  because the number could be false at like 5436 - thus, I will get True, but I need to get False because 6>3.

Any tip please?

---

EDIT:
SOLVED, Thanks ALL!

Comment: Did you mean to add `return True` to the end of the first version of your function?

Comment: not exactly return True, but yea.
I mean, I want the code to work, to get the list ascending from right to left, if its 5432 its good, but if its 5436, its bad, and if its 3456 - its also False

Comment: Any tip for how to delay the return True on the list to the end of the list?

Comment: Surely you want your function to return either `True` or `False`? The first version of your function can return `None`.

Comment: How will None help me?

Comment: It doesn't. I guess you didn't mean to return `None`.

Comment: And yea, I need it to return False or True ( after I am finishing this with a loop, I am trying to do it recursively, which is the point of me doing it, I am pretty bad with recursions and such, I got a tip that if I will make the code work with iteration first - I can change it to a recursive slowly, I will try it after I finish it, but firstly I have to make it work iteration)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def is_ascending(lst):
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if lst[i] >= lst[i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: What the heck? lol.

Comment: How does it work to me? I tried a similliar code with return True at same spot, but it didnt work to me, I did lst[i] <= lst[i+1] and such. I will debug and check, but its weird...

Comment: I changed indexes when comparing two elements and now it doesn't generate an error.

Comment: Yea, I noticed it, but how is it that now it works? What is the difference between the indexes? why now it works?

Comment: For example 5432

length of 5432 is 4. A cycle needs to do 4 steps.
lst[i] <= lst[i+1]
1) 5<4; 2) 4<3; 3) 3<2 4) There is no number in the list and we have an error, 2 was last.
lst[i] >= lst[i-1]
We start from 4 and compare it with the first number.
1) 4>5 2) 3>4 3) 2>3 and no more because this cycle has 3 steps.

Comment: Ohhh yeaa, I just realized, yea... because the length is 0 1 2 3, but I did up to 4, and it doesnt exist... Uhh, I turned out to be an idiot :( Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should add `return True` at the end of the function. Plus the function should make sure its doesn't run off the end of the list and also perform the correct comparison:

```py
def is_ascending(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

print(is_ascending([1,2]))
print(is_ascending([2,1]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: I tried with return True before, at the end of the function.
But the problem is I didnt know that I should add len-1.
Mind sharing the reason for it?

Comment: The `len(lst)-1` is to make sure that the `lst[i+1]` doesn't cause an IndexError.

Comment: Ohh, so my code would have worked if I just added the lenlst - 1... Ahh, its new to me, about the -1 that wont cause index error. Its a good tip actually, it might help me also in the future. Thanks alot!